# How to show time picker with Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

How to show material time picker using jet compose?

> implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha02'
> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha01'

I got an error message
**Unresolved reference: supportFragmentManager**

```
  val context = LocalContext.current
                        //Creating a MaterialDatePicker.Builder instance that gives us a single date selector.
                        val builder : MaterialDatePicker.Builder<*> = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker() // 1
                        //Building-up the MaterialDatePicker by calling a builder.build function
                        val picker : MaterialDatePicker<*> = builder.build()  // 2
                        //Display the Material Date Picker.
                        picker.show(context.supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())   // 3
```

Answer (score 3):

.supportFragmentManager is part of AppCompatActivity and not Context itself. You need to cast LocalContext.current to the Activity your Composable is hosted in. Please note that your Activity might extend ComponentActivity and not AppCompatActivity, you will need to change that.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
val supportFragmentManager = (LocalContext.current as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager
```